# Recommended way to delete object in MongoDB based on a route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

New to the MEAN stack development, but loving it!  I want to ask this question in such a way that it isn't opinion based, so forgive me if it is.

Lets say I have an admin dashboard that lists out the objects in a MongoDB collection.  Each item has a delete button that has a href of this scheme: `href="/admin/ministry/delete/:id"` where `:id` is the id of the object in the DB to delete.

Right now I have a route setup that successfully routes the request to the controller, but I'm wondering if this is the best way to delete an object.  For example, once I click on the delete button for an object, it gets deleted and we are back to the dashboard, but then the URL remains something like this: http://localhost:3000/admin/ministry/delete/554b88546d280ab11603b062

So essentially my question is, what suggestions would you have for my route and controller when it comes to deleting an object from the DB.

**Router**

```
var admin_ministry_controller = require('./controllers/admin/ministry_controller.js');
app.get('/admin/ministry/delete/:id', ministry_controller.delete);
```

**Controller**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Ministry = mongoose.model("Ministry");

exports.delete = function(req, res) {
    Ministry.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).exec(function(err, ministry){
        if(ministry) {
           ministry.remove();
        }

        var query = Ministry.find();
        query.exec(function(err, doc) {
            res.render('admin/ministry', {title: 'Next Steps | Ministry', msg: "Deleted Ministry", ministries: doc});
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use RESTful API structure. Just take a look at what the API will look like: 
[image: RESTful API]

In your case, to delete `ministry`, users should send a `DELETE` request to `/api/admin/ministry/:id`.

And the router should be like this:

```
app.delete('/admin/ministry/:id', ministry_controller.delete);
```

Comment: I understand this concept and it makes perfect sense.  But what I am asking is what if I want to be able to click on a link and delete an object that way.  You can only make `GET` requests by clicking on a link, I unsertand I can do it with AJAX too as I've already done that.
I mean is the best way to create a form for each object that is listed with `method=delete`?

Comment: You are correct, you need to specify method `delete` for each item so it will send `PUT` request. Did you tried like this? `<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/api/admin/ministry/1" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>`