# Deleting a topic in node with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a project with node, express, mongo. I am trying to delete a topic.

This is my code:

```
router.get('/:id/delete', function(req, res, next){
var topicId = req.params.id;
console.log('Logging topic id: ' + topicId);

Topic.findById(topicId, function(err, topic)
{
      if(err)
      {
        console.log('There was no topic with this ID');
        return next(err)
      }
      else
      {
        Topic.remove(topicId, function(err){
            res.render('/mytopics');
            console.log('Topic deleted successfuly');
        });
      }
});

});
```

The thing is it won't even come into the first console log where I am logging the topic id. So I am wondering if my query is built right?

Comment: no, it does not work. just tired that ...

Answer (score 1):

In RESTful API structure the `delete` route should expect `DELETE` request. Try out following code:

```
router.delete('/:id/delete', function(req, res, next) {
// ...
```

For additional resources about this issue be sure to check out:

[Recommended way to delete object in MongoDB based on a route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169944/recommended-way-to-delete-object-in-mongodb-based-on-a-route/30171076#30171076)